# How to import photos from new iPad 5 Mini to old 2015 MacBook Air, OSX 10.9.5

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, photos.app, import

I'm trying to import photos from a new iPad that uses the newer Photos app to an old 2015 MacBook Air (OSX 10.9.5) that only has the old iPhotos app, but it's not working.

I keep getting an error on the Macbook saying I need a passcode on the iPad, but there's no request for a passcode on the iPad, and I've already selected 'Trust'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple say](https://www.apple.com/uk/ipad-mini/specs/) that this iPad requires OS X 10.11.6 or later and iTunes 12.8 or later to sync with a Mac, so I'm going to guess that you're out of luck trying to use it with iPhoto.

You could try:

- Seeing if you can download the photos using the **Image Capture** app on the Mac (Launchpad > Other, or find it in the Applications folder)
- Transferring the photos via a service such as Dropbox
- Upgrading the Mac to a more recent version of macOS - it should be easily capable of running the latest version and give you a better experience all round. 10.9.5 is pretty old now and is no longer supported with security updates etc, so it's a good idea to upgrade. If you really don't want to go straight to 10.14 for some reason, [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201475) has links under **Learn More** from which you can get the previous three versions.

Comment: Thanks @nekomatic, I didn't know an upgrade for this device was supported.

Comment: Image Capture looks useful too.